# Incorrect line ending

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

So I have a project I worked on a few months ago. After I installed Windows 8 I decided to reinstall Eclipse and import my old project and have a look again.
So everything worked fine installed the ADT and SDK.

Then I tried start the project and it said I had an error.. So I had a look and saw this.
[image]

and this: 
[image]

I cant seem to understand what these errors mean and how to fix them.
If anyone has a solution or an idéa please let me know.

Regards
Niklas

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13400684/43662

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a formatting error. press ctrl+shift+F. Then save , clean and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution what I came across

Solution 1: - Open layout file Ctrl+Shift+F (Command+Shift+F in MacOSX) Save the layout file and close it. Delete any .out files the builder might have created. Clean project.

Solution 2: - Also you can select the complete code, cut it and then paste it again. This will not disturb your xml formatting as well.

Solution 3: For few of the coders it works just after cleaning the project

Hope this will help. Please do let me know if I can be of any help