# Unknown XML Block error in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am trying to build my Android project in Eclipse and this error is popping up in my console:

```
W/ResourceType(  265): Unknown XML block: header type 0 in node at 413
```

This is causing my R.java to not generate. I have absolutely no idea what this means. It's not even telling me which file is causing the error. This is quite a large project with many XML files and I've looked through every single one and they all seem to be okay. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please, put here your xml file

Comment: Have you cleaned your project and regenerate it?

Comment: Yes I've cleaned it many times @PiyushGupta

Comment: You need to post the XML layout file that you are having the issue with. Nobody will be able to help you without it

Comment: I have many layout files @Boardy Like I said it's a big project. I don't know which one is causing the error.

Comment: look at the "Marker" or "Problem" section in your eclipse and it will show  you from which file the problem originates.

Comment: As Sajan, the problem section will show you the error and if you double click on the error, it will take you to where the error is located. Also, if you expand the directory where the layout files are located, any files with an error in will show a red cross next to the file name

Comment: @Boardy None of the XML Files have errors on them(no red crosses). Also, this issue is not showing up on the "Problem" section in Eclipse. It only shows in the "Console" when I build my project.

Comment: Oh that's odd. I'm not sure then, never seen that before. Have you got all the XML files in the correct directory, if you've created different layout folders within the res folder are you sure they have the correct names

Answer (score 0):

R.java includes all Ids, layouts.. If there is any problem like formating error in id name or any other error of layout. then R.java file will not be generated & your java class file will show you error. so first check your xml file

Answer (score 0):

There might be the possibility that you have put your `xml file` in the wrong folder under `res` dir. Like if you are trying to access `<wallpaper>` tag in Android xml file you must put it in `res/xml` directory otherwise it will show error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following options::

1. close other projects.
2. clean your project.
3. check in the source files(java classes), if there import android.R.* is present , remove that.
4. check in your res folder, if it is showing error in any folders like drawable, layout, values.
   5.correct if you get errors.

R.java is not coming because it is not getting id of any/more resource/resources.

this will solve your problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your error may come from incorrect line ending. You should check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400684/strange-xml-error-incorrect-line-ending). Hope this help.